# AWS Lambda Layers Performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Are there any measurable performance advantages to AWS Lambda Layers related to cold start, runtime, or deployment/install time, or is the primary advantage the modularization and sharing of code?

Comment: Probably not, but also there also don't seem to be any performance disadvantages either. There is a nice comparison of layer vs non layer response times here: https://medium.com/consulner/performance-of-aws-lambda-with-and-without-layers-9bffbb5434f3

Comment: It's a good writeup, thanks. My only concern would be that Java is a performance outlier (like .NET) on AWS Lambda. Makes me wonder if the numbers would be proportional or not to the 1st tier Lambda runtimes: Python and Node/JavaScript.
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/aws-lambda-cold-start-language-comparisons-2019-edition-%EF%B8%8F-1946d32a0244
https://www.nuweba.com/blog/benchmarking-invocation-overhead-on-new-aws-lambda-runtimes

Comment: The latter. It's about packaging/sharing. There's perhaps a small chance if you have one common layer and many independent packages using that layer, that Lambda may keep the layer itself in its cache for longer than it keeps a given Lambda package (because *many* Lambdas use the same layer so that layer might be evicted from a cache more slowly than a given Lambda package), but we don't know much about Lambda's cache strategy so I wouldn't bet on much difference here. I'd expect Java layers to exhibit the same cold start characteristics as Java packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.

An example use case is a lambda that needs a big, unchangeable, datastore to operate. Then it might be a performance boost to have it via layer instead of downloading it dynamically over and over again.

In addition, it spares space in the deployment package, which allows both faster deployments and console editing.

Last, the latest feature from AWS, extensions, uses layers to run an additional process on the same container (next to the lambda) and thus allowing parallelism.
As a disclosure, I'm working on a company named Lumigo that troubleshoot serverless applications, and we used layers to have *the whole python runtime* so we could have a single extension that works on all the runtimes (reference: https://github.com/lumigo-io/lambda-log-shipper)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first purported advantage related to a "big, unchangeable, datastore"? How will code being loaded from a layer plus a package improve things vs. loading from a simple, larger (aggregate) package?

Comment: you can put some of your code's dependencies in layers, here is a reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path, so basically, your lambda could be just a single line that calls to a dependency that does everything

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't seem to support your first assertion. How will the movement of a large, static data structure from package to layer cause improved performance (at either cold start, warm start, or runtime)? Or are you simply referring to the time taken during deployment, when calling UpdateFunctionCode for your package?

Comment: Oh, let me rephrase myself: there are two advantages: (1) move code to layer to reduce deployment time (calling to UpdateFunctionCode) and (2) move big binary files to layer to avoid downloading them every time and spare runtime.

Comment: I don’t think your #2 advantage is correct. Layers doesn’t make it any quicker at runtime. If anything, it might be marginally slower because instead of fetching and unzipping a single (larger) ZIP file, it’s fetching, unzipping, and organizing multiple (smaller) ZIP files. Do you have any evidence, documentary or otherwise, for this?

Comment: layers fetch this data during the cold start phase, in which (1) you don't pay for that time and (2) the container have stronger resources. Here are good references: https://medium.com/@hichaelmart/shave-99-93-off-your-lambda-bill-with-this-one-weird-trick-33c0acebb2ea https://lumigo.io/aws-lambda-performance-optimization/how-to-improve-aws-lambda-cold-start-performance/

Comment: Here is a very good investigation on lambda layers -> https://medium.com/consulner/performance-of-aws-lambda-with-and-without-layers-9bffbb5434f3